# Call ember component action from grandchild component - Ember 2.x

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to call from Ember component action from another component, that is 2 level higher (grand parent). I can call action from parent component using parentView. Is there some way to not forwarding that action in middle component.
I'd like to change base-table property after sortable-header click.

```
{{#base-table}}
   {{#base-table-header}}
      {{#header-item}} Item {{/header-item}}
   {{/base-table-header}}
{{/base-table}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the action down in the template

```
{{#base-table as |table|}}
   {{#base-table-header}}
      {{#header-item on-click=table.blink}} Item {{/header-item}}
   {{/base-table-header}}
{{/base-table}}
```

#### base-table.hbs

```
{{yield (hash blink=(action "blink"))}}
```

#### base-table.js

```
...
actions: {
    blink() {
        //...
    }
}
...
```

#### header-item.js

```
...
this.attrs['on-click']()
...
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly, what I was looking for :)